# Executing a read after transaction completes produces an error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to read the updated document data after running a transaction against a ref and I'm getting an error saying

> Firestore transactions require all reads to be executed before all writes.

I'm a tad confused because I'm running my `get`s after the transaction execution resolves. Can anyone help explain this or point me in a direction to getting the updated doc object?

Below is how I'm trying to return the new value:

```
return db.runTransaction(t => (
  t.get(meetingsRef).then(doc => (
    t.update(meetingsRef, { count: doc.data().count + 1})
  ))
)).then(t => t.get(meetingsRef).then(doc => doc.data()));
```

Comment: What line of code does your error occur on?  What is your last line of code attempting to do in the `then` callback? It doesn't seem to have a purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The Promise that is returned by the transaction runs after the transaction is completed. At that point you can't read/write data on the transaction object (your `t`) anymore.

You're probably looking to read the resulting document from `meetingsRef` directly.

Comment: Are you saying to call a `get` on `meetingsRef` inside my then? I'm not sure what type is being returned in the transaction promise but i figured i could use it to get the new data.

Comment: The transaction returns whatever you return from within its callback. But that won't be the most up-to-date document snapshot. You *can* return `doc.data()`, but reading the latest document from `meetingsRef` is probably simpler.